# #NoMethodError (undefined method `reject' for 0:Integer

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, nomethoderror

I am using ruby 3.0 and rails 7.0.2 for my application. when i try to run console or generate controller or migration it gives me this error:

`` NoMethodError (undefined method `reject' for 0:Integer Did you mean?  rect): ``

```
if existing_problem_sets.present? 
  existing_problem_sets.each do |problem_set| 
    problem_set.update!(
      sat_question_id: problem_set.sat_question_id.reject{|x| x==self.id.to_s}, 
      sat_position: problem_set.sat_position.reject{|x| x[:sat_question_id] == self.id.to_s}) 
  end #do
end #if
```

Comment: You should post some code to better understand your problem.

Comment: What command exactly do you run? What is the full error message including the whole stacktrace?

Comment: `sat_question_id` is integer

Comment: You should add the code in the question instead of in the comment.

Comment: Must check please how to add and resolve it

Answer (score 0):

> `sat_question_id: problem_set.sat_question_id.reject{|x| x==self.id.to_s}`

[@mechnicov comment may be the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72285157/nomethoderror-undefined-method-reject-for-0integer#comment127709397_72285157).

- The error message tells you that the  method `reject` does not exist in the Integer class (it is "undefined")
- Immediately you should be telling yourself "I need to lookup the Integer class in the Ruby docs."
- Where is `reject` being called? Right there! so `sat_question_id` might be/must be an integer.
- What are the current values of the object(s) in that code? If they are correct then maybe the code is wrong. What object(s)/Classes do I have that have a `reject` method?

Based on this snippit - `x==self.id.to_s` - I am going to GUESS you meant to code something like this:

```
sat_question_id: problem_set.reject{|x| x.sat_question_id.to_s == self.id.to_s},
```

Nobody's answer will be better than a guess without seeing your data class(es) declarations and some actual instantiated objects. The actual object that caused the accident.